# Swashbuckle add custom header to some methods only

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger

I have successfully add custom header using `IOperationFilter` in my .net core application, now my problem is how to filter it out for certain methods only in the `SomeController` class.  Is this achievable? This is my current code:

**Startup.cs**

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        // some swagger services here.
        c.OperationFilter<SomeFilter>();
    });
}
```

**SomeFilter.cs**

```cs
public class SomeFilter: IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (operation.Parameters == null)
                operation.Parameters = new List<OpenApiParameter>();

        operation.Parameters.Add(new OpenApiParameter
        {
            Name = "Some-Custom-Header",
            In = ParameterLocation.Header,
            Required = false,
            Schema = new OpenApiSchema
            {
                Type = "String"
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**SomeController.cs**

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class SomeController: Controller
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost("some_method1")]
    public IAction SomeMethod1() // this method should not include custom header filter
    {
        return Ok();
    }
    
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost("some_method2_with_authorize")]
    public IAction SomeMethod2() // this should have the custom header in swagger
    {
        return Ok();
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet("some_method3_without_authorize")]
    public IAction SomeMethod3() // this should have the custom header in swagger
    {
        return Ok();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way on how to exclude the method that will exclude the said methods by doing this:

```cs
public class SomeFilter: IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        var methodName = context.ApiDescription.ActionDescriptor.As<ControllerActionDescriptor>().ActionName;
        var hasExcludedMethod = ApiFilterSettings.AppSettingsFilterMethods.ToStringList().Contains(methodName);
        if(hasExcludedMethod)
           return; // return directly when an excluded method is found;**strong text**

        if (operation.Parameters == null)
                operation.Parameters = new List<OpenApiParameter>();

        operation.Parameters.Add(new OpenApiParameter
        {
            Name = "Some-Custom-Header",
            In = ParameterLocation.Header,
            Required = false,
            Schema = new OpenApiSchema
            {
                Type = "String"
            }
        });
    }

}
```

I hope this will help you guys.